# Add button to exchange web interface

Tags: c#, exchange-server, office365, exchange-server-2010, webui

I'm in charge of providing a poc for the following feature: add a button to the outlook web ui when creating an appointment to refer to a page for a catering service. When users would click on that button they'll be taken to a page where they can order sandwiches and the like. I should provide a bit of information to the page such as begin and end date time for the appointment in the link.

I've looked around and I've found [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb891875(v=exchg.140).aspx) that explains how to add a button to the Exchange/Outlook web ui, but I have no idea how to add functionality to that button. Or where I should put the code so Exchange takes it into account. Can you smart people help me on my way? Any article that describes how to add a button to the Outlook web ui and add functionality to that button is welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure why this post is getting downvoted, maybe because it's a little hard to understand what you are going for here. The link you provided is about Exchange Server 2010 and is not valid for Office 365. However, if you are looking for a solution for Office 365 that works for both Web and Outlook Desktop, Mail Apps may be the solutions you want. Please take a look at http://aka.ms/appsforoutlook - if it looks like it would be useful, I can answer your question more in detail.

Comment: This put me on the right track. It's what I was looking for. I didn't know that the Outlook web interface was part of Office 365. I thought it was something build into Exchange Server to have an interface to get to your mails. If you submit this as an answer, I'll happily mark it as solved.